# Error al validad permisos para android 6.0 permiso de localizacion

Tags: android, geolocalización, localización

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Buenas tardes estoy tratando de obtener mi ubicación de mi gps por medio location manager, ya tengo mi clase hecha solo que al momento de ejecutar mi app me manda un error por que tengo android 6.0 y tengo que validad permisos, ya hice mi validadcion pero aun así me manda error

Clase location manager

```
public class MiServicio extends Service implements LocationListener {

    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

    private static final int MY_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 1 ;
    private static final int MY_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION = 1 ;

    private final Context context;

    double latitud;
    double longitud;
    Location location;
    boolean gpsActivo;
    TextView texto;
    LocationManager locationManager;


    public MiServicio() {
        super();
        this.context = this.getApplicationContext();
    }

    public MiServicio(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        getLocation();

    }

    public void setView(View v) {
        texto = (TextView) v;
        texto.setText("Coordenadas:" + latitud + longitud);
    }

    public void getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) this.context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            gpsActivo = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        if (gpsActivo) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
                    (this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
                    (this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((MainActivity) context,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                } else {

                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((MainActivity) context,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                            MY_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

                }

                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((MainActivity) context,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) {

                } else {

                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((MainActivity) context,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                            MY_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);

                }


                return;
            }
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER
                    , 1000 * 60
                    , 10
                    , this);

            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            latitud = location.getLatitude();
            latitud = location.getLatitude();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }


}
```

codigo en mi activity principal

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int MY_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 0;
    private View mLayout;
    private String comments = null;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        MiServicio servicio = new MiServicio(getApplicationContext());
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });


    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                } else {

                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle saveInstanceState)
    {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);

        MiServicio servicio = new MiServicio(getApplicationContext());

        servicio.setView(rootView.findViewById(R.id.ubicacion));

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



}
```

Error que manda

> 05-13 15:47:34.802 9303-9303/mx.com.oncontrol.localizacion E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   Process: mx.com.oncontrol.localizacion, PID: 9303
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mx.com.oncontrol.localizacion/mx.com.oncontrol.localizacion.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.content.Context.checkPermission(java.lang.String, int, int)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
>                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.content.Context.checkPermission(java.lang.String, int, int)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                    at android.content.ContextWrapper.checkPermission(ContextWrapper.java:637)
>                                                                                    at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ContextCompat.java:387)
>                                                                                    at mx.com.oncontrol.localizacion.MiServicio.(MiServicio.java:25)
>                                                                                    at mx.com.oncontrol.localizacion.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:50)
>                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6245)
>                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
>   05-13 15:47:39.915 9303-9303/mx.com.oncontrol.localizacion I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 9303 SIG: 9

Comment: ya que es un servicio y no una activity, deberías usar `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission` en lugar de `ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission`

Comment: me marca error si lo cambios

Comment: Elenasys te adjunte una imagen del error que me manda al tenerlo con this

Comment: Acabo de ver, veo que requiere en realidad la actividad, mala nota para mí =( , realiza este cambio cuando instancies MiServicio ,  MiServicio servicio = new MiServicio(getActivity()); , me dices que resulta por favor.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando instancies MiServicio,  envía la activida por ejemplo:

```
 MiServicio servicio = new MiServicio(getActivity());
```

y cuando requieras los permisos agrega el parametro de la variable `context`, en lugar de `this` :

```
 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                            MY_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
```

Comment: si lo tenia asi en un principio pero me mandar un error

Comment: añadi la imagen donde te muestro que lo tengo con this, pero me manda un mensajito de error

Comment: Hugo, agregué una actualización a mi respuesta...

Answer (score 0):

No puedes pedir permisos desde un servicio porque puede estar ejecutándose en segundo plano. Lo que sí puedes hacer es gestionarlo desde la aplicación avisando al usuario de que el servicio no funcionará sin permisos.

Y si lo que quieres es avisar al usuario inmediatamente, puedes enviar una notificación que te abra una actividad que gestione el permiso.